# Div is truncating words and border on wrapping

Tags: css, xhtml, word-wrap

Maybe this is simple, but is making me nuts.
To understand the problem, the easy way is to look at the image.

[image]

Div width is truncating either word or the rounded border(also in case there is a space or dash between words). How can I force each "a" element to go into a new line if width is not enough to contain the element?

Here's the code

```
<div id="post-tags">
    <span class="tag-title">Tagged:</span>
                            <a href="#">tag2</a>
                            <a href="#">tag3</a>
                            <a href="#">tag4</a>
                            <a href="#">longtag5</a>
                            <a href="#"li>longtag6</a>
                            <a href="#">longtag7</a>
                            <a href="#">longtag8</a>
                            <a href="#">longtag9</a>
                            <a href="#">longtag10</a>
                            <a href="#">longtag11</a>
                            <a href="#">longtag12</a>
                </div>
```

And the CSS

```
   #post-tags{
     width: 560px;
     float: left;
     padding: 15px;
     font-size: 11px;
     } 

  #post-tags .tag-title{
     color: #6b6b6b;
     padding:  5px 0 0 5px;
    }

 #post-tags a{
     line-height: 24px;
     padding: 3px;
     background: #a7d1e3;
     padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
     margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    }

 #post-tags a:hover{
     color: #a7d1e3;
     background: #205F82;

    }
```

Comment: i cant reproduce the error shown on the image...( http://jsfiddle.net/ybyjm/ ) i change the size and it never cuts the tags

Comment: Are you on Quirks mode (ie. not using a valid `doctype`?) I remembered answering a question with this exact symptom, and that was the cause.

Comment: Sorry I don't mentioned I am in Chrome 8.0.552.231, the same in the latest Safari. Ok in firefox, don't have tried with IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it doesn't work corerctly in chrome. A solution could be to float the elements. so you add `float:left;` for the selectors `#post-tags .tag-title` and `#post-tags a`. Of course now you will see that there is need to modify and padding and margins. A solution close to yours is applying `margin: 0 2px 10px;` and `padding: 0 10px;` for `#post-tags a` so your new css will seems like the following:

```
#post-tags {
    width: 560px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 11px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#post-tags .tag-title {
    color: #6b6b6b;
    padding:  5px 0 0 5px;
    float:left;
}
#post-tags a {
    line-height: 24px;
    padding: 3px;
    background: #a7d1e3;
    margin: 0 2px 10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float:left
}
#post-tags a:hover {
    color: #a7d1e3;
    background: #205F82;
}
```

here a live example: http://jsbin.com/adika4